# Python: Method .as_matrix will be removed in a future version. Use .values instead

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have the following code

```
train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X.as_matrix(), y.as_matrix(), test_size=0.25)
```

where `X` is a DataFrame and `y` is a series.
When calling the function above, I get the following warning:

> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: FutureWarning: Method .as_matrix will be removed in a future version. Use .values instead.
>
> """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

Then I tried to change using `.values` as mentioned in the warning:

```
train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X.values(), y.values(), test_size=0.25)
```

But I get the following error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X.values(), y.values(), test_size=0.25)
>
> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

How do I solve this?

Comment: That should be as simple as removing `()` from `values()`.

Comment: you are right, my bad..

Comment: From pandas 0.24, use `df.to_numpy()`, not `.values` or `as_matrix()` either.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html

Though they suggest using `.values`, as @cs95 mentioned, `.to_numpy()` was the one that worked for me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be:

```
train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X.values, y.values, test_size=0.25)
```

See [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values).

Answer (score 3):

According to Panda 0.25.1 documentation, they recommend more using DataFrame.to_numpy() than DataFrame.values()

> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values

So I'd like to suggest to update it like below:

```
train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X.to_numpy(), y.to_numpy(), test_size=0.25)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some additional info regarding the versioning behind the warning. I hope it helps.

It occurred for me due to pandas version (0.23.4) that is shipped now in SQL Server 2019 along with Anaconda Python 3.7.1. SQL Server 2017 shipped with pandas (0.19.2) which is part of Anaconda Python 3.5.2 where this Future Warning msg did not occur.

[pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html) got deprecated since version 0.23.0. See [PR](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/18458).

[Examples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values) of how to use pandas.DataFrame.values.