# Object has no attribute

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am learning python/numpy. I followed instructions but somewhat code does not working.

```
    import numpy
    import os
    desktop = os.path.normpath(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop"))
    import pandas
    x = pandas.read_csv('Desktop/numpy exc/2dcsv.csv',header = None)
    print(type(x))
    print(x.info)
    y = x.as_matrix()
    print(y)
```

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'as_matrix'

Comment: Maybe a version problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382440/python-method-as-matrix-will-be-removed-in-a-future-version-use-values-inste (which version of pandas>)

Comment: As an aside, you should use `print(x.info())` instead of `print(x.info)`.

Comment: Thank you, I did not notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `x.as_matrix()` try `x.to_numpy()`.

In panda's documentation it says:

```
Deprecated since version 0.23.0: Use DataFrame.values() instead.
```

Comment: to_numpy() is the thing i normally use. I just added deprecation information as extra.

Answer (score 3):

[pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix()](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/18458) is deprecated. Use [pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) instead.

Comment: The documentation of [pandas.DataFrame.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values) recommends to use `pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy()` instead.